# Random number being appended to file name for camera images in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am taking a picture through camera on my app. I use a method to create a temporary file before saving the output to it.

When I create the temporary file, its file name is how I want it to be like - yyyyMMdd_hhmmss in dateformat.

But when I call the photoUri, a random number is being added onto the file.

Where is this number coming from and How I can stop it from adding onto the image file? the extra number looks like this 451308260449067127 and its always random everytime.

```
@Override
public void onOtherButtonClick(ActionSheet actionSheet, int index) {

    String[] galleryPermissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, galleryPermissions)){

        //Camera
        if (index == 0) {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;

                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                }
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    Uri photoURI = null;
                    //

                    // N is for Nougat Api 24 Android 7
                    if (Build.VERSION_CODES.N <= android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
                        // FileProvider required for Android 7.  Sending a file URI throws exception.

                        photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                                photoFile);


                        Log.v("File Name",photoURI.toString());

                    } else {
                        // For older devices:
                        // Samsung Galaxy Tab 7" 2 (Samsung GT-P3113 Android 4.2.2, API 17)
                        // Samsung S3
                        photoURI = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
                        Log.v("lowbuild",photoURI.toString());
                    }

                    //Starts the intent to camera where extra output is stored as photoURI
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                    Log.v("Extra",MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT.toLowerCase().toString());
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 0);
                }
                else{

                    // IF create file somehow returned an empty file
                    Log.v("file", "photo file is null");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Photo file is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        }


private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = timeStamp;

    Log.v("time",timeStamp);
    Log.v("image",imageFileName);


    File storageDir = new File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Camera");

    if(!storageDir.exists()){

        boolean s = new File(storageDir.getPath()).mkdirs();

        if(!s){
            Log.v("not", "not created");
        }
        else{
            Log.v("cr","directory created");
        }
    }
    else{
        Log.v("directory", "directory exists");
    }

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".png",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    uriOfImage = Uri.parse(image.getPath());
    return image;
}
```

Edit: None of the answers are helping me.

I am debugging like this.

```
    Log.v("image2",imageFileName);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName, /* prefix */
            ".png" ,         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    Log.v("file",image.getAbsolutePath());

imagefilename is - 20180220_040841
But file abosolute path is - /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20180220_0408412097619931102966329.png
```

Comment: Use String Split function to remove the end number 451308260449067127 and then you can add your timestamp

Comment: The time stamp is correct. It does name the file the way i want it. But it still adds this 19 digit number to the end of the file.

Comment: if you are using cursor to insert the image at that time it may be adding timestamp extra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how [`File.createTempFile()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) works - it takes your prefix, suffix and directory and returns a `File` that didn't exist before. In practice that happens by [appending a large random number](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/libcore/ojluni/src/main/java/java/io/File.java#generateFile).

If you don't want that, don't use `createTempFile()` but one of the regular [`File` constructors](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

```
long msTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date dt = new Date(msTime);
String format = "yyMMddHHmmssSSS";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
String PhotoFileName = String.format("Photo%s", sdf.format(dt).toString());
String saveFilename = PhotoFileName + ".png" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss", Locale.US);
Date now = new Date();
String fileName = formatter.format(now);
```

Do like this.

The random number you are getting is time in ms.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss", Locale.getDefault());
String timeStamp=dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Use above code to get timestamp.

Comment: I tried this. Timestamp is correct. But when a temp file is created, some numbers are still being appended.

Answer (score 0):

Use  this way in your createImageFile() method

```
  File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
       System.currentTimeMillis()+".png",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
);
```